# Why is my Rust webserver failing to build on Google Cloud Build?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, rust, google-cloud-build

I am trying to build my web server, written in Rust, on [Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run).

When I build the image locally on an Apple M1, it works:

```
$ docker build -t foo .
...
Successfully built cf1125710221
Successfully tagged foo:latest
```

When I build the image on [Google Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build), it fails:

```
$ gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/my-webserver-398017/foo .
...
Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.66
error: failed to run custom build command for `proc-macro2 v1.0.66`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/target/release/build/proc-macro2-f45860c8afe2be80/build-script-build` (signal: 4, SIGILL: illegal instruction)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=build.rs
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
The command '/bin/sh -c cargo build --locked --release' returned a non-zero code: 101
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 101

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

BUILD FAILURE: Build step failure: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 101
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build 1c268317-ab3e-4bfa-96c1-32aa2e57b3c0 completed with status "FAILURE"
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```bash
# Build container:
FROM alpine:latest
COPY . .
RUN apk update
RUN apk add build-base curl libressl-dev
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y --default-toolchain nightly
ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"
RUN cargo build --locked --release

# Server container:
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update
RUN apk add libressl-dev ffmpeg
COPY --from=0 target/release/my_webserver .
```

I tried the following:

1. I initially thought the build might be failing because of [this issue](https://github.com/dtolnay/proc-macro2/issues/398) but I can see from the logs that it's building the latest proc-macro2 version which no longer has that issue.
2. I tried setting the `-vv` flag in the `cargo build` command but the extra verbose output didn't reveal any more useful information, just that it was running the build script for that crate.
3. I also tried using `debian:latest` as the base image and the same compilation error occurred.
4. I tried setting `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 alpine:latest` in the Dockerfile to reproduce the problem locally on my Apple M1, but it did not reproduce the issue.
5. I tried removing all the unstable code from my webserver and switched to using the `stable` toolchain but the same compilation error occurred.
6. I have updated to the latest crates with `cargo update` but the same problem occurs.

I'm not sure what else to try. Why is the proc-macro2 crate failing to compile? What am I missing?

**Edit:**

I ran `cat /proc/cpuinfo` on the machine:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 0
microcode   : 0xffffffff
cpu MHz     : 2200.158
cache size  : 56320 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap xsaveopt arat md_clear arch_capabilities
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs taa mmio_stale_data retbleed
bogomips    : 4400.31
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 0
microcode   : 0xffffffff
cpu MHz     : 2200.158
cache size  : 56320 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap xsaveopt arat md_clear arch_capabilities
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs taa mmio_stale_data retbleed
bogomips    : 4400.31
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: `SIGILL` means that a program tried to execute an instruction that doesn't exist on the target CPU. In your case that's the `proc-macro2` build script (i.e. its `build.rs`). Do you know what CPU Google Cloud uses for its VMs?

Comment: Interesting. I just ran `cat /proc/cpuinfo` on the machine and copied the output into my question. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was missing `gcc` as a dependency:

```
RUN apk add build-base gcc curl libressl-dev
```

I have no idea why this resulted in a SIGKILL.